# using custom build event in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am in the process of creating a visual studio solution to wrap the command-line portions of OCaml.  In the standard OCaml make file there is the following target:

```
version.h : ../VERSION
echo "#define OCAML_VERSION \"`sed -e 1q ../VERSION`\"" > version.h
```

which I was hoping to simulate via a custom build event.  I have modified my vcproj file to include the following lines:

```
    <CustomBuildStep>
  <Command>C:\Windows\System32\sed.exe -e "1 s/^/#define OCAML_VERSION "  "$(SourceDir)VERSION"  &gt; "$(SourceDir)version.h"
  </Command>
  <Inputs>VERSION</Inputs>
  <Outputs>version.h;%(Outputs)</Outputs>
  <Message>Building version header file ....</Message>
</CustomBuildStep>
```

I do have sed installed on my system (from unxutils), and the command does work correctly from a command terminal (after macro-expansion naturally).  However, when I execute it from inside Visual Studio I get the following error message:

```
CustomBuildStep:
  Description: Building version header file ....
 'C:\Windows\System32\sed.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

I've seen this problem on several forums and the proposed solution is to include the absolute path (which I did) or set the working directory to where the executable lives.  Is there anything that I could do to get this to work?